# Spark-submit job throws NoSuchMethodError at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig.setFairness(Z)V

Tags: java, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming

My spark streaming job (spark 1.6)  is trying to store data in Redis cluster, when I run it locally it worked fine, when deploy it on the cluster, I got the below stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig.setFairness(Z)V
        at com.xyz.utils.redis.RedisClient.<init>(RedisClient.java:87)
        at com.xzy.redis.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:76)
        at com.xyz.spark.broadcastvariables.RedisCacheWrapper$RedisCacheHolder.getDevelopmentInstance(RedisCacheWrapper.java:29)
        at com.zyx.spark.broadcastvariables.RedisCacheWrapper$RedisCacheHolder.<clinit>(RedisCacheWrapper.java:18)
        at com.zyx.spark.broadcastvariables.RedisCacheWrapper.getCache(RedisCacheWrapper.java:74)
        at com.zyx.spark.sparkjob.ProcessArticles.lambda$null$0(ProcessArticles.java:380)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
```

I am using `redis.clients:jedis 2.9.0` and this jar depends on `org.apache.commons:commons-pool2 2.4.2` which contains the setFairness() method.

I know it is a dependency conflict problem between my uber jar dependencies and spark dependencies, as I found that spark classpath depends on a different version of `commons-pool`.

I've tried:

1. to use --jar option to add my commons-pool2
2. to use `spark.executor.extraClassPath=true`

And both trials failed.

Could anyone help?

Thanks